# C# System.speech.synthesis post processing

Tags: c#, speech, speech-synthesis, post-processing

Is there any way to apply post processing effects(change speed, pitch, volume) of the output from [system.speech.synthesis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#. To be more clear I am calling system.speech.synthesis.SpeechSynthisizer.Speak(String); and I want to edit the output. Thank you for your help.

Comment: note sure. but may be use this [`SetOutputToWaveFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586883%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and then modify the wave file with NAudio library or some similar tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the volume and rate using the property **Volume**  and **Rate**

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            synthesizer.Volume = 100;  // 0...100
            synthesizer.Rate = -2;     // -10...10

            // Synchronous
            synthesizer.Speak("Hello World");

            // Asynchronous
            synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Hello World");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[SpeechSynthesizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx) let's you set a lot of properties that you mentioned here. What do you mean by post processing effects? Once you call the Speak function, any changes to the Synthesizer will not apply towards the output. You could potentially save the output to file and try to apply additional effects if you wanted. Perhaps us [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586885(v=vs.110).aspx) function provided on the Synthesizer.